# To get a average % of two columns

Tags: mysql

I have the columns as mentioned below

```
1)OldOrderQty
2)NewOrderQty
3)OLdunitRate
4)NewUnitRate
```

My issue is i need to get % of savings 
if there is any savings for the new unit rate

Please help me out with this 
thanks a lot for any answers

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?  What is the exact definition of "savings" in your problem - do you take into account the quantity?

Comment: Old unit rate mite be high compared to new unit rate in that case the savings. has to be find out in terms of percentage

Answer (score 2):

Your question and terms aren't well defined, but this is what I'd lean towards:

```
SELECT 100*(1-NewUnitRate/OLdunitRate) AS percent_savings
FROM table
```

So, for example, if your `OLdunitRate` was 10, and your `NewUnitRate` was 7.5, your percent savings would be 25%.

Comment: That makes more since. I didn't see she was referring to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
3 * 1 = x
4 * 2 = y
```

y / x = would be the savings I presume